# Generating string in code when one of a group of properties change

Tags: wpf, binding, properties

I am seeking advice on how to be notified when one of many properties change.

For example, lets say I want to bind a control's text to a FullAddress property in my WPF ViewModel that I can calculate on the fly whenever one of a set of properties changes, such as StreetNumber, StreetName, Suburb, PostCode etc.

I am thinking that I need to bind my displaying control to the FullAddress property, but how do I have it automatically update whenever one of the dependent properties changes? Can I bind the property's codebehind to multiple other properties on the same ViewModel? If so how? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only option here is to have objects of your class subscribe to their own INPC events and change their dependent properties automatically. The workflow would go like this:

1. Object is created
2. Object subscribes to its own INPC
3. A dependent property is changed
4. The INPC subscription detects that a dependent property for `FullAddress` has changed, and updates the `FullAddress` value
5. The `FullAddress` setter fires its own INPC event
6. WPF detects that `FullAddress` has changed and updates the UI

**Update:** Sample code

```
class NotificationExample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }

        set
        {
            this.firstName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this.lastName; }

        set
        {
            this.lastName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.firstName, this.lastName); }
    }

    public NotificationExample()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += this.NotifyIfFullNameChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void NotifyIfFullNameChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "FirstName" || e.PropertyName == "LastName")
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, another fast answer. Its taking me time to get my head around this. I sort of understand but in step 4 how does the INPC subscription know which properties are depended upon by the FullAddress property? I presume by Object you mean the instance of the class that contains the FullAddress and dependent properties, does the Object itself call PropertyChanged on the whole object as opposed to just one property?

Comment: The INPC subscriber would be a private method in your class. It would "know" what FullAddress is dependent on because you know it (if e.PropertyName == "StreetAddress" etc). The object is what you said. PropertyChanged is always called on a specific property, you can't call it "on the whole object". For this to work, both FullAddress and its dependent properties need to call PropertyChanged from within their setter.

Comment: Thanks! I'm nearly there... so if I understand correctly, when you say 'Object subscribes to its own INPC' do you mean that in each property that FullAddress depends on, I call PropertyChanged for that property but I also call OnPropertyChanged for the FullAddress property as shown the code samples? Or is there a way for an object to get notified from the WPF dependency property backend that something within the object has changed? Sorry Im not sure about the link between the private method and the INPC subscription.

Comment: Check the code above, this is what I meant (see constructor and `NotifyIfFullNameChanged`). This is essentially the same thing as Dean Chalk's answer, implemented a little bit differently.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for persevering, that makes sense now. Great code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged then you can notify within any property setter. E.g

```
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            Address.BeginEdit();
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    #endregion

    public string FirstLine
    {
        get { return firstLine; }
        set
        {
            firstLine = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstLine");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullAddress");
        }
    }


    public string SecondLine
    {
        get { return secondLine; }
        set
        {
            secondLine= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondLine");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullAddress");
        }
    }

    public string FullAddress
    {
        get { return firstLine + secondLine; }
    }
```

Comment: David thanks for the very speedy response, and for the code, this makes all kinds of sense. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
public class Address : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string address1;
    public string Address1
    {
        get { return address1; }
        set
        {
            address1 = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Address1");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullAddress");
        }
    }

    private string address2;
    public string Address2
    {
        get { return address2; }
        set
        {
            address2 = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Address2");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullAddress");
        }
    }

    private string town;
    public string Town
    {
        get { return town; }
        set
        {
            town = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Town");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullAddress");
        }
    }

    public string FullAddress
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", address1, address2, town);  }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Dean I thank you as well for the fast answer, great minds think alike apparently, I'm impressed with the agreement between yours and the first answer. I will study this code.

Comment: I think we posted at about the same time, and they are both correct

Comment: Pity, I dont seem to be able to vote Helpful to any posts yet, sorry this is my first time on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and do not use FullAddress property at all
**EDIT**:
If you only need to *show* the full address you can use `StringFormat`

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
            <Binding Path="City"/>
            <Binding Path="Street"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If you wish to allow users edit the whole address string and then split it into parts then you need to implement [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) interface

Comment: Thanks alpha-mouse I read other posts about MultiBinding before asking but I have a feeling I would still need to invoke a value converter to build the FullAddress from its components, right? Or possibly a stringformat attribute if it doesnt require much formatting?

Comment: @TripleAntigen: i edited my answer. Yes, you'll need either converter of format string, but you'll not need listening to property changes yourself: binding mechanism will do it for you